# Pthreads with timeout

Tags: php, multithreading, timeout, pthreads, kill

PLS im new in multithreading. I needed to call multiple funcions at the same time. so i made this code. it works fine response time is long as longest funcion return. i mean it write my result from function after all functions complete.. but sometime happens some funcion is not responding (that functions sent request to insurance company and it return price of insurance). i need some timeout. if that thread is not return any result in that timeout, i need to kill that thread and echo results from other threads

PS: sry about my english i hope u understand me :)

```
$input = Array(
'form_pzp_vozidlo_vykon'=> '55',
'form_pzp_objem_motora' => '500',
'form_pzp_rok_vyroby'   => '2014'
);

class MyWork extends Threaded {

    public $name;
    public $input;

    public function __construct($name, $input) {
        //echo "Constructing worker $name<br>";
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    public function run() {
      if ($this->name) {
            $motor_func = 'pzp_'.$this->name;
            $motor_vysledok = $motor_func ($this->input);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($motor_vysledok);
            echo '</pre>';

        }
    }

}

class MyWorker extends Worker {
    public function run() {}
}

$pool = new Pool(1, \MyWorker::class);
$pool->submit(new MyWork("union",$input));
$pool->submit(new MyWork("axa",$input));
$pool->submit(new MyWork("uniqa",$input));
$pool->shutdown();
```